# Rolling median of date-indexed data with duplicate dates

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My date-indexed data can have multiple observations for a given date.
I want to get the rolling median of a value but am not getting the result that I am looking for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2020-06-22', '2020-06-23','2020-06-24','2020-06-24', '2020-06-25', '2020-06-26'],
    'value': [2,8,5,1,3,7]
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

[image]

```
# Attempt to get the 3-day rolling median of 'value':
df['value'].rolling('3D').median()

# This yields the following, i.e. one median value
# per **observation**
# (two values for 6/24 in this example):
date
2020-06-22    2.0
2020-06-23    5.0
2020-06-24    5.0
2020-06-24    3.5
2020-06-25    4.0
2020-06-26    4.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

# I was hoping to get one median value
# per **distinct date** in the index
# The median for 6/24, for example, would be computed
# from **all** observations on 6/22, 6/23 and 6/24(2 observations)
date
2020-06-22    NaN
2020-06-23    NaN
2020-06-24    3.5
2020-06-25    4.0
2020-06-26    4.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

How do I need to change my code?

Comment: can you please post the output that you would like to obtain. specifically how exactly duplicate dates should be handled

Comment: I changed my question to include the desired output. To re-phrase my objective: I want the calculation to compute the median of all observations in a given (rolling) time window

Comment: Rolling window doesn't work this way if you want to get distinct values then your result set (on which you are applying rolling) should have distinct data. Rolling with window = 3 will  pick 3 days and give you median for eg for 26th it will till pick 24th and find of 4,4 and 3.5 give median as 4 median.

Comment: Thank you, Divyaansh! If I cannot use rolling, what would I use to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your code produces the right answer for the second occurrence of `2020-06-24`, as 3.5 *is* the median of 4 numbers 2,8,5,1. The first occurrence of `2020-06-24`only uses its own value and the ones from the two prior days. Presumably, and I am speculating here, it is looking at the '3D' window in the elements in the rows preceding it in the timeseries, not following.

So I think your code only needs a small modification to satisfy your requirement and that is if there are multiple rows with the same date  we should just pick the last one. We will do this below with `groupby`. Also you want the first two values to be `NaN` rather than medians of shorter time series -- this can be achieved by passing `min_periods = 3` in the `rolling` function. Here is all the code, I put the median into its own column

```
df['median'] = df['value'].rolling('3D', min_periods = 3).median()
df.groupby(level = 0, axis = 0).last()
```

prints

```
         value  median
date        
2020-06-22  2   NaN
2020-06-23  8   NaN
2020-06-24  1   3.5
2020-06-25  3   4.0
2020-06-26  7   4.0
```